# Opensource project inFlutter with good architecture

Tags: flutter, dart, mvvm, architecture

Do you know real open source projects on Flutter using architectures like MVVM, MWWM, MVP, Clean Code Architecture are used?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at the code of the example application for the just expired flutter slide puzzle challenge offered by VeryGoodVentures.
https://github.com/VGVentures/slide_puzzle